# Is it possible to use => to define objects?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the arrow-constructor to create an object:

```
var Countable = (data) => {
    return data;
}
```

But when creating an object:

```
new Countable(newSubscriptions)
```

I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: (data) => {
    return data;
} is not a constructor
```

I get the expected output by doing

```
var Countable = function(data) {
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use an arrow function to create new objects:

```
var Countable = () => {
    return {}; // This function returns a new object
};
var o = Countable();
```

However, you can't instantiate an arrow function, because it doesn't have the [[[Construct]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-new-operator) internal method. So using [`new`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-new-operator) will throw.